# Compatibility of titanium and TideSDK

Tags: titanium, tidesdk

As far as I know TideSDK is what used to be Titanium Desktop, right?

I'd like to ask if somebody has experience in reusing (mostly the business logic and data access) components of Titanium mobile in TideSDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ive developed for both and in my experience Titanium for mobile and TideSDK are fairly incompatible at this point.

[This is one of the reasons Appcelerator open sourced](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2012/01/the-future-of-titanium-desktop.html) the project and stopped working on it. It was diverging so much from their company goal of a robust mobile API that it did not make sense for them to work on it. The API's at this point are very different, as well as the technology and workflow, across the dev stack from UI to business logic, to data access, to backend.

The only parts I was able to reuse were pure JavaScript utility files, and the Titanium local DB access scripts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your experience. So I may reuse propably at most my Domain Objects and plain (API independent) Logic?

Comment: That's all I could reuse, and some odds and ends of the API, but those were usually accidents. But, I still love TideSDK, since it usually covers all my Desktop application use-cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use most of your javascript code within TideSDK without much modifications. There is fundamental difference between various UI components on Desktop platforms and Mobile platforms. Taking example .. in desktop your application have window..and u can have separate UI Items like system tray, taskbar etc. whereas in mobile you would generally control the entire screen and various UI components are very different than desktop.

This is why you need to implement the native interfaces in desktop and mobile separate way but most of the business logic would remain unchanged.